How to mock library dependencies in an Azure Function app without adding the libraries as dependencies of the test project?
I want to test an Azure Function app (.NET 8) using Moq.
The solution consists of two projects:

AssetGovernace (source)
AssetGovernace.Tests (tests)

While I can easily mock out IApplicationService, IApplicationNotificationRepository, and IQueueService, like:
var _applicationServiceMock = new Mock<IApplicationService>();

I don't know how to mock out IMapper (AutoMapper), IConfiguration, and ILogger, without including relevant package dependencies of AssetGovernance to AssetGovernance.Tests for making the interfaces available. Is that the right approach?
When looking into this sample repository, I don't see the test project addressing my issues.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-functions-code-testing-sample/tree/main
How should I mock out these framework and library dependencies in an Azure Function app?
ApplicationGovernanceService class:
public class ApplicationGovernanceService(
    IApplicationService applicationService,
    IApplicationNotificationRepository applicationNotificationRepository,
    IQueueService queueService,
    IMapper mapper,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    ILogger<ApplicationGovernanceService> logger)
    : IApplicationGovernanceService

IApplicationGovernanceService interface:
public interface IApplicationGovernanceService
{
    public Task CheckApplicationOwnership(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

Bonus: Is there a way to have dependency injection in the test project?

There is no need to mock AutoMapper, just use the real thing.

@LucianBargaoanu How to decide whether to use the real thing or mock it out?

If it's easy enough to use the real thing, you should, that way you're closer to the actual system. AM doesn't depend on anything external and it's fast enough to use in tests.

You don't write that you're using test-driven development (TDD), so I'm assuming that you don't, but I'll bring it into the discussion anyway, because it's relevant to this discussion, too.
An often-mentioned benefit of TDD is that it makes design problems visible earlier than you would otherwise have noticed them. This would have been the case here, too. The tests only highlight a problem.

I don't know how to mock out IMapper (AutoMapper), IConfiguration, and ILogger, without including relevant package dependencies of AssetGovernance to AssetGovernance.Tests for making the interfaces available.

This is, in a nutshell, the problem. If an interface ships with its implementation, it violates the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) because in order to depend on the abstraction, you must also depend on the implementation detail.
This is the problem you're running into here. The interfaces are defined together with their implementations. If you want to follow the DIP, you should, at best, ignore all interfaces defined by dependencies. Instead, you could define your own. According to the DIP,

"clients [...] own the abstract interfaces"
- APPP, Robert C. Martin, chapter 11

In other words, client code, in this case AssetGovernace, should define the interfaces it needs. When it, instead, pulls in third-party interfaces, it breaks the DIP.
You could argue that using those third-party interfaces is 'pragmatic', and you're allowed to do that. After all, no law says that you should follow the SOLID principles.
If you chose to do so, however, you'll also need to add those dependencies to the test code if you want to use Moq to replace them with Test Doubles.

Thank you, Mark! You say: "you'll also need to add those dependencies to the test code". By dependencies by you third-party interfaces?

I'm using AutoMapper heavily in my project. I really don't want to mock it, and hardcode the mapped entities. Is it okay to use AutoMapper with its profiles in tests?

You say: "because in order to depend on the abstraction, you must also depend on the implementation detail"? Why is that? Couldn't I implement e.g. IConfiguration myself to mock it out?

When the test project references the source code project, it has access to all the packages of the source code project. So, all dependencies of the source code project are available in the test project. I said the opposite in my original question.

@Shuzheng If the interface ships in a library that also includes the 'default implementation', you can't avoid pulling in the implementation when you pull in the interface.

Yes, I agree. But I could create my own mock implementation. Why would a library ship with an interface, if it’s the only implementer?

@Shuzheng Yes, indeed, why? You'll need to ask those library designers that question, rather than me. I have some hunches, but none that I care to share.
